# Windows 7 Installer capable of UEFI mode

Tags: windows-7, uefi

I've been looking for an installer of windows 7 like in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sDm8rWr3dV8) that has the files required for UEFI mode.

Sample image:

I've tried different version of 64 bit Win7 such as (Home, Pro, Ultimate) but didn't find those files.

I have windows 8, and I saw these files. But I want to install win7.
My question is, how can I have this version of win7 that is capable of UEFI?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create EFI bootable installation media by creating folder `\EFI\Boot\` and adding file from existing Windows installation `C:\Windows\Boot\EFI\bootmgfw.efi` as a `bootx64.efi` to it.
So you'll have `\EFI\Boot\bootx64.efi`.

Comment: I was referring to IA64, since I didn't know that Windows 7 for IA64 wasn't released. I'm taking that back. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I believe `Windows Server 2008 R2` was the last version of Windows that has supported IA64. I honestly wouldn't have guessed you were going down the IA64 dirt road.

Comment: @week Do you mean, I can just copy the needed files from windows 8 installer going to win7? BTW, my laptop has no OS yet.. it will be a fresh install..

Comment: @fiberOptics In case you have only install files, you may use `7zip` to unpack `bootmgfw.efi` from `boot.wim`. @Ramhound It's just a subliminal message from KB articles, stucked in my head :)